# Creating UUID on Linux Command-Line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, uuid

What's the latest solution to create a random [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) in up-to-date Linux/Ubuntu?

The [answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/103359/how-to-create-a-uuid-in-bash) is rather out-dated.

Comment: What's wrong with `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`?

Comment: Nothing. This is a way of creating UUID on Command-Line that I didn't know before.

Comment: It's mentioned in the second answer in the question you linked to :)

Comment: "_second answer_", that means the first and **_accepted answer_** is out-dated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change another computer's network settings from Powershell and/or .NET?](https://superuser.com/questions/103359/how-do-i-change-another-computers-network-settings-from-powershell-and-or-net)

Comment: <Sigh>, to all those people who thinks Command-Line is Windows -- it is **not**. Windows "_borrows_" the term from Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` seems to do the trick.